# show an image into fragment: doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml

i want to show an image into a fragment so in the xml i wrote

But it doesn't displayed. Why? Where is the problem?

Uptdate my question with more code.

Comment: Please post more relevant code.

Comment: Can you post all the xml content?

Comment: post your fragment code.

Comment: Where you want your image? You need to understand that you are using a RelativeLayout you need to set a position to your imageview

Comment: I wwant it at center of screen

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't like to give the solution that way but here it goes, try to understand your layout first, why are using a RelativeLayout in that case? And how the RelativeLayout works